# Unable to Install gcc in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I've updated, upgraded, did full updates, and other recommendations, but I still receive this error.

[image: First Part of Terminal]
[image: Second Part of Terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Please post text, not screen shots.

That said... Those are network connectivity errors.

I'd change your hosts to your country specific ones or a close to you (network wise) mirror. I like educational institutions that are geographically close to me.  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Once you've done that, re-update your sources via `apt-get update` and then install GCC.  And personally, I'd install GCC et. al. by simply `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: As an addition to the above, I would recommended to `apt-get purge gcc` and then do `apt-get install build-essential` instead; this to get the gcc that belongs with the build-essentials - for a higher probability of a trouble free installation.